# iOS6 CLPlacemark to show street name

Tags: ios, ios6, mapkit

I want to show the full street name of the user location, with the below code I can only show the city name :

```
-(void) reverseGeocode:(CLLocation *)location{
   CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {    
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
        return;
    }  
    if(placemarks) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks [0];
        NSArray *lines = placemark.addressDictionary[ @"FormattedAddressLines"];
        NSString *addressString = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        NSLog(@"Address: %@", addressString);
    }
}];}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the street name ?

Answer (score 10):

I'm actually using this code to get a complete location:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLPlacemark *placemark;
@property (strong) CLLocationManager *gps;
@property (strong) CLGeocoder *geocoder;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    gps = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    gps.delegate = self;
    gps.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [gps startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

                aLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@",
                                placemark.thoroughfare,
                                placemark.subThoroughfare,
                                placemark.postalCode,
                                placemark.locality,
                                placemark.country];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

but you can get more if needed by using other CLPlacemark properties:

**From CLPlacemark.h:**

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name; // eg. Apple Inc.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *thoroughfare; // street address, eg. 1 Infinite Loop
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subThoroughfare; // eg. 1
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *locality; // city, eg. Cupertino
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subLocality; // neighborhood, common name, eg. Mission District
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *administrativeArea; // state, eg. CA
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subAdministrativeArea; // county, eg. Santa Clara
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *postalCode; // zip code, eg. 95014
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *ISOcountryCode; // eg. US
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *country; // eg. United States
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *inlandWater; // eg. Lake Tahoe
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *ocean; // eg. Pacific Ocean
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *areasOfInterest; // eg. Golden Gate Park
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I am getting null, no values are shown. What's wrong then ?

Comment: I updated the answer with more info. Did you do the same? Remember that without an internet connection the address can't be obtained.

Comment: Could you explain why you used placemark = [placemarks lastObject] while some other people are actually getting the first object in the array of placemarks? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks [0];
NSArray *lines = placemark.addressDictionary[ @"FormattedAddressLines"];
        NSString *addressString = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
        NSLog(@"Address: %@", addressString);


NSString *street = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
NSString *city = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
NSString *state = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
NSString *country = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
NSString *zip = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
```

Comment: kABPersonAddressStreetKey is undeclared identifier, where is the declaration ?

Comment: @Al_fareS `import AddressBook.ABPerson`

Answer (score 0):

don't miss to add AddressBook. Framework and add :

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

also for your use:

```
if(placemarks) {
  CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks firstObject];
  NSString *addressString = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
  NSLog(@"Address: %@", addressString);
}
```